# How do I copy weblinks to answers?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

I normally just copy paste, but look at what happened in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873421/how-to-reduce-this-to-sturm-liouville-form/873469#873469):

> A good example on the wikipedia page: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm–Liouville_theory

Some people embed it. Can someone tell me the correct code for doing that?

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/520/links-urls-containing-special-characters-are-not-recognized-by-markdown (and other posts listed there among linked questions, for example, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017/link-copying-causes-misinterpretation-in-mark-down-in-comments).

Comment: Also percent encoding can be used to solve this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory Some browsers do this automatically when copying a link from the address bar. Or this can be done manually, or using some available, tools. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/carets-stop-hyperlinks-working ) If you are using Ctrl+L in the editor, this should be done for you by the SE editor.

Comment: Related: [Markdown doesn't recognize URLs with non-ascii characters](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12659/markdown-doesnt-recognize-urls-with-non-ascii-characters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell, your link contains an "en dash" between `Sturm` and `Liouville`, and it is *this character* that is causing the problem. Replacing it with the ordinary "hyphen-minus" `-` seems to work:

- original: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm–Liouville_theory
- hyphen-minus: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm-Liouville_theory

The same problem appears to occur even when using fancier link constructs:

- `<http://www.bare-url.com>`

  - original: [http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm–Liouville_theory](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory)
  - hyphen-minus: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm-Liouville_theory
- `[link text](http://www.example.com)`

  - original: [Wikipedia page](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory)
  - hyphen-minus: [Wikipedia page](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm-Liouville_theory)

(If you are anti-hyphen-minus and really want to keep the en dash, you can also replace the en dash character with the HTML character code `&ndash;` — http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm–Liouville_theory)

---

This appears to be a known behaviour in the system.  [balpha's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82713/214632) indicates that if you use the link button (or `Ctrl-L`) to add the link, the problematic characters will be automatically escaped.

Testing: [creating a link using Ctrl-L](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory).  Seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Being *disgustingly* lazy, I find it tiresome to move between Math.SE and an external page twice: to copy-paste   the **title** of the page and its **URL**.

So I made a [little bookmarklet](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC#copy) which, when executed on any page, generates a  link in Markdown's `[text](URL)` format, using either the text you selected on the page, or (if none) the title of the page. The URL is properly escaped. At least in Chrome and Firefox, which are the browsers I tested.

Comment: I forgot to test some of my recent bookmarklets in Firefox... reworking them now. :(